# PHP coding doubts

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I have a code in one of my controller files in laravel, below code is in `Teamcontroller.php` file:

```
$faqs = Faq::portal()->get()->toJson();
$glossaries = Glossary::portal()->get()->toJson();
```

Similarly, we have faq and glossary controller.

I am not able to understand what exactly the above code means. I tried to find function inside the Faq model and Faq controller and glossary model and controller, but i am not able to find any function portal.

Can anyone please explain to me what the above code means and where can I get reference to portal?

Comment: `portal()` is a static function from both `Faq` and `Glossary` classes. Can't you find them in these? If not, are these classes extending another class?

Comment: Do Faq and Glossary have parent/super classes? portal() may be defined in one of the a parents.

Comment: Which framework are you using? If you cannot find portal in Faq or Glossary, you may find in their base class.

Comment: I am using Laravel framework. I did a grep command on all the files and folder still i did not  find any reference to Portal function.

Comment: Could you post your Faq and Glossary models?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does a lot of magic, in your case it seems to be a **Query Scope**, from laravel documentation:

> Scopes allow you to easily re-use query logic in your models. To define a scope, simply prefix a model method with scope

This is their example:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }

    public function scopeWomen($query)
    {
        return $query->whereGender('W');
    }

}
```

and it is called as follows:

```
$users = User::popular()->women()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

So in your case, you should have a method called `portalScope` in either the given class, or a parent one.

You can read about [query scopes here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes)